# Why can't I re-download a previously downloaded game from the PS Store?

Tags: ps4, farming-simulator-2019

I downloaded *Farming Simulator 2019* from the PS Store and cannot re-download it.

It doesn’t show up in library or the PS4 store. I have tried going into library but nothing is showing up.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you know the particular game? It's possible it might have been completely removed from the store and might not be downloadable anymore. I believe this has happened with other PS titles. It's quite rare though.

Comment: yes it is farming simulator 19 and it is still in the ps4 shop

Comment: Make sure you're looking at your "purchased" section of the library. I think it defaults to installed. (Also check if you're logged into the right account)

Answer (score 4):

Given that the game you are having problems is Farming Simulator 2019, there is a good chance you acquired this game while it was apart of the May 2020's monthly free PS+ games<sup>[1](https://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2020/04/29/free-playstation-plus-games-for-may-2020-revealed)</sup>, and then you canceled your PS+ subscription sometime afterwards.

There are a few sources ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlayStationPlus/comments/covngx/comment/ewlgi53/) and [GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/74292724)) that have stated that games will occasionally (though not always) disappear from your library if they were apart of the free PS+ games after canceling their subscriptions. If this is the case, then you'll need to re-subscribe to PS+ to gain access to these games again

Comment: i bought it late 2020 but i had bought the game with money

Comment: @bruce_gray0 First off, welcome to Arqade! Have you tried checking your transaction history around the time you purchased the game? You can access that via the web on Sony's website. If you are logged into the same account that purchased the game, it would appear there either with the amount you paid, or as $0.00 if was free from PS+